# Cause Mono completion from a scheduled task

Tags: spring-webflux

What I need to do, in a spring cloud gateway v2 filter's `filter()` method:

- Send a message via a message queue to some other application
- Respond to the client only once a response message was received
- If the response message doesn't arrive in due time, retry a few times, then respond with a 500 status

Any idea how?

My current attempt (too much code, IMO, to list everything here):

- create a `Runnable` which does stuff, once the response message is received
- place the Runnable on a `ScheduledExecutorService`, with a delay
- place the returned `ScheduledFuture` and the `Runnable` in a map
- cancel and remove the `ScheduledFuture` from the map when the `Runnable` is executed
- have the listener to the incoming queue look up the `ScheduledFuture` in the map, execute the corresponding `Runnable` and cancel the `ScheduledFuture`, when a message matching the `Runnable` is received
- return a `Mono.fromRunnable(() -> scheduledFuture.get())` from `filter()`

What I expect to happen:

- The message gets sent to the other service
- once a response is received, the `ScheduledFuture` is canceled but the `Runnable` is still executed
- `ScheduledFuture.get()` finally completes, regardless how (i.e. normally of with an exception) and the `Mono` returned from the `filter()` method finally completes.
- If the completion was without error, go on and return the `Mono` from the `filter()` method, otherwise, if the number of retries was not exhausted, restart the process
- If the response is never received, or not in due time, the ScheduledFuture.get() also completes, but with an error, so retry also on this path, if number of retries not exhausted

What I don't like - and don't know if it will work - is that `ScheduledFuture.get()` is blocking. Plus, it's a rather involved way of doing things. I suspect there's a simpler way, since I expect this to be a rather frequent need - pass on operations via message queues and respond to http clients after response messages are received also via message queues, except when a response message doesn't arrive in due time.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Why are you even considering futures and other java 7 things when you have webflux and reactor on your classpath and you can use their Schedulars and executors? It seems to me that you need to read the reactor docs

Comment: Also your entire question is way waaay to broad. Your first point, send a message from a message queue can be done in 100 different ways? What type of queue how is the message sent, what does the data look like. Etc. So no voted to close, too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using even a more basic concurrency mechanism: `ReentrantLock` and `Condition`. I could not find any mechanisms in project reactor which allow a `Mono` to wait on a logical condition combined with a timeout for *completion*, rather than for sending a message, and spring webflux relies heavily on empty `Mono`s.

Like this - simplified:

```
public class Example {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor;

    public Mono<Void> handle() {
        
        Message message = makeMessage();
        
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                scheduledExecutor.schedule(() -> sendMessage(lock, condition) , 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                while (true) {
                    if (checkCondition() || messagingAttempts >= attemptsSoFar) {
                        break;
                    }
                    condition.await();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        })
        .and(afterMessageSending())
        .onErrorResume(exception -> {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return makeErrorResponse("Unexpected transient internal server error. Please try again.");
        });
    }
    
    private ScheduledFuture<?> sendMessage = null;
    
    private void sendMessage(ReentrantLock lock, Condition condition) {
        if (sendMessage  != null && !sendMessage.isDone()) {
            sendMessage.cancel(false);
        }
        if (checkCondition() || messagingAttempts >= attemptsSoFar) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    condition.signal();
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            queue.add(message);
            sendMessage = scheduledExecutor.schedule(() -> sendMessage(lock, condition) , timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
    
    // return true when the condition you hope will become true once the message you send is processed
    // something in your code outside of this class also needs to call sendMessage() once more, after checkCondition() becomes true
    public abstract boolean checkCondition();

    // do whatever processing you need done, then return a Mono<Void> - but one that completes only after all processing you need done is finished
    public abstract Mono<Void> afterMessageSending();
}
```

What it does:

- creates a `Mono` from a `Runnable` which:

  - acquires a reentrant lock (i.e. a lock that can be acquired multiple times by the same thread without causing errors)
  - calls a method which adds a message to a queue - or could do anything else that you need done before the returned `Mono` completes
  - starts waiting on a condition created for the acquired lock - with a timeout, so the wait isn't forever
- in the method which sends a message:

  - cancels the scheduled execution of the message sending method, if there's anything to cancel, but so that any execution in progress is not interrupted
  - if the logical condition to wait for is not yet met, simply sends a new message and reschedules itself
  - otherwise signals the `Condition` object on which the `Mono` is waiting, causing the Mono's `Runnable` to continue and eventually complete, thus causing the `Mono` to complete

If `checkCondition()` never becomes true, after a number of attempts the scheduled task will stop rescheduling itself. If some external code causes `checkCondition()` to become true and then calls `sendMessage()`, the currently scheduled task will still be canceled, and the condition on which the `Mono` waits will be notified, before the time at which the task is scheduled to run. Either way, after the sending of a message (or anything else that `sendMessage()` might do) plus waiting for its effects ends, the `Mono` is completed, and this completion happens almost instantly after the `Condition` on which the `Mono` waits is completed. So, worst case, sending the messages doesn't do anything, and the `Mono` completes after having waited for several scheduled `sendMessage()` to execute and for the effect of their processing to become apparent, or, best case, `checkCondition()` becomes true very quickly after the first message is sent, and some external code calls `sendMessage()` immediately after that, causing the `Mono` to complete before even a single wait cycle is complete.

`Condition.await()` gives up the lock and releases the thread for other processing, once called. When signaled, `Condition` re-acquires the lock for the thread that gets to continue the execution of the `Runnable`. This makes the whole process non-blocking and thread-safe - execution cannot be done, for the `Mono`'s runnable, while the lock isn't held, and the lock can only be held by a single thread. But also, the lock isn't held while the message sending happens, so no thread is blocked while `Condition.await()` happens.